# CSS - Parent child selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
.recipe
  .ingredients
    = f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient|
      = render 'ingredient_fields', f: ingredient
  .row#links
    .col-xs-12
      = link_to_add_association "", f, :ingredients
  %hr
```

I need to select the ingredients div using jquery in the format of `$("#links")["closest"](".recipe > .ingredients")` but this doesn't select anything.

It's frustrating though as `$("#links")["closest"](".recipe > .row")` will return the correct div.

Fiddle of what works and what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/yL6dr4s1/

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what the rendered HTML looks like?  Maybe a JSFiddle example?

Comment: @Seano666 sorry I forgot to include a link, I have added it! - https://jsfiddle.net/yL6dr4s1/

Comment: Is your question about jquery or about how to feed this selector into cocoon?

Comment: @nathanvda it was about cocoon but "disguised" as a general question to allow for a larger audience to attempt to help me. The accepted answer though has worked for me, I didn't realise the siblings traversal method worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to jQuery documentation, [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method tries to find element matching the selector by testing **the element itself and 
traversing up through DOM**.

It does not go through siblings of the element.

Based on your requirements, it seems like you want to traverse the tree for getting match in siblings. jQuery has [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to do that. So one solution would be to use siblings method like:

```
$("#links")["siblings"](".recipe > .ingredients")
```

Another soultion would be to get closest parent and then use children as answered by @mhodges

As for the query `$("#links")["closest"](".recipe > .row"):`

It works fine because closest method finds the match in the element itself.

Here is the example to showcase that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Match found because it is parent
  console.log($("#links")["closest"](".wrapper").length);
  // No match found because element is sibling
  console.log($("#links")["closest"](".row1").length);
  // No match found because element is sibling
  console.log($("#links")["closest"](".row3").length);
  // Match found because it is element itself
  console.log($("#links")["closest"](".row2").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row1">
    <span>Content1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row2" id="links">
    <span>Content2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <span>Content3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your requirements on using the exact selector/syntax you provided, but this selector works exactly how you want it to.

```
$(this).closest(".recipe").children(".ingredients").append('<br/><input type="text" value="Flour">');
```

## Edit

This is the closest I could get:

```
$(this)["closest"](".recipe").children(".ingredients").append('<br/><input type="text" value="Flour">');
```

Comment: The requirement is that I am using a gem, called cocoon, in rails to nest the fields. The source code uses that syntax and I am trying to work out how to use it without modification.

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease Gross. okay, I will keep working on it using the given syntax. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease Idk what to tell you man, ["closest"](".recipe > *") is coming back with only the .row div, but ["closest"](".recipe").children() returns both the .ingredients and .row divs. I can't find documentation for ["closest"] anywhere, so I am not entirely sure what it's doing. On the surface it seems like it's doing the same thing as .closest(), but it's only allowing certain combination selectors after that and acting very strangely. You have officially stumped me!

Comment: I know right! It's making it very difficult, I guess I'll just let the gem creator know what we've found out! It's so strange

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the selectors in the way you propose.

As far as the DOM is concerned (and jQuery), the element defined by `ingredient` and the element defined by `row` are not related.  You have to traverse up to the parent element, then back down to get to the child.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/yL6dr4s1/2/) that hopefully demonstrates the issue.

If you can change it so that `ingredient` and `row` are both within the same parent div, you might have more luck with your test selector syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery gets to buggy, doesn't have a certain option or just becomes to messy to use for a certain operation, it is good we also have access to good old plain javascript.

```js
document.querySelector('#addToIngredients').addEventListener('click' , function(e) {

  var recipe = getClosest(e.target,'recipe');  
  if (recipe) {
    var ingred = recipe.querySelector('.ingredients');
    ingred.innerHTML += '<br/><input type="text" value="Flour">';
  }
  
});

function getClosest(elem,cls) {
  var el = elem.parentNode;
  while (el){
    if (el.className.indexOf(cls) > -1) {
      return el;
    }
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe">
  <div class="ingredients">
    <input type="text" value="Eggs"><br/>
    <input type="text" value="Flour">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" id="addToIngredients">Add to .ingredients</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Of course they can be combined

```
$(function() {
    $("#addToIngredients").on('click', function(e) {
      var recipe = getClosest(e.target,'recipe');  
      if (recipe) {
        var ingred = recipe.querySelector('.ingredients');
        ingred.innerHTML += '<br/><input type="text" value="Flour">';
      }
  });
})
```